# Integrate MOSS 2007 with Outlook 2007 - Without exchange server

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, outlook, moss, ms-office

I want to integrate my MOSS server with outlook i.e. emails to be sent and received from MOSS. How can I do it without using the exchange server?
Currently i have jst thought abt setting up a document library and email enable it so that it can receive emails. But what will I do for sending the emails and what about outlook meeting requests etc. Any suggestions?

Please also let me know is it even possible or not...

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint outgoing email is just SMTP email so you can use any SMTP server.

[MSDN - Plan outgoing e-mail (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262844(office.12).aspx)

Edit - From Rias comment I think he may be asking about [Outlook Web Access - OWA](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/code/OWA/index.html)

Comment: that means i have to create a form for sending email. but basically my problem was that how would i imitate outlook's functionality in MOSS without the exchange server at the backend.

Comment: Your question makes no sense Ria - can you please clarify and edit the question?

Comment: Are you talking about OWA? Seriously though - if you want a clear answer you've got to ask a clear question.

Comment: I m sorry if the question was not clear enough. I want the functionality of OWA but the OWA web parts use an exchange server on the backend right? 
I dont want the dependency on exchange server.